# Fit all content inside a HTML page designed using bootstrap in the viewable area without need to scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I am setting up a simple php page to graphically display data. Used bootstrap 4, php, mysql and chart JS for this project and able to build a pretty page with all the info I need. Now I am facing challenges with fitting all this data (12 graphs, in 12 cards) into the viewable area, so that when loaded it auto fit the screen (without cutting off) and no need to scroll the page. This I could do by zooming out the page in the browser, but want to know of any good alternative CSS/js way to do this as zooming out is making the font look bad. I tried putting the body element as 100vh and overflow hidden, but it's not acceptable as it's cutting the data and simply hiding the scroll bar.

Below is the sample fiddle

```
jQuery('body').css('height', '100vh').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
```

JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ogmvn07e/1/

Comment: JS fiddle to explain the scenario : 

https://jsfiddle.net/anilbhrth/ogmvn07e/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=ogmvn07e

Answer (score 0):

If you put the entire page content into a wrapper div or header then you can set the height of that element to 100vh and the overflow to hidden. I've just tried it with your JS fiddle and got it working. You may need to then add in media queries to display it properly on tablet and mobile.

```
<header>
  <!-- content goes inside --> 
</header>

header {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried wrapper couple of times and it always truncates the lower part to fit the page and locks the scroll bar. Is there a way to make all content fit the page with out cutting out the data. Sorry I am new to web designing and this is my first project, Can you explain how I can achieve this? Actually, I am planning to project the data on a big screen to show the stats and want the data to fit properly on it without losing the content and need to scroll.

Comment: Yeah the header will truncate the lower part of the tables in viewed in a smaller screen. Possible you could add in drop-down tables/charts instead? that way you could display the first row fully and the other rows could be drop-down? "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/" This may help you :)